# Why is the range from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

When I run this code

```
FromPolarCoordinates /@ {{3/2, π/3}, {3/2, (5 π)/3}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I search the documentation of `CoordinateChartData`,[There](http://wolfram.com/xid/0e49ng57pglmdy-xynf1u) is a example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why the range is from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ in  polar coordinates? In my textbook the range is $[0,2\pi)$. And I use `PolarAxes -> True` in `PolarPlot` it will show the range from `0` to `2 Pi`.(It seems the `PolarAxes` have some bug so that the ticks cannot display in full.)

```
PolarPlot[{1, 1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PolarAxes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So can anybody give an explanation for this??

Comment: The choice happens to coincide with the range of the two-argument arctangent. Use the explicit formula instead if you have to deal with angles outside that range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `FromPolarCoordinates` does this range checking is that for most curvilinear coordinate systems, the variables aren't "angle-like" (cyclic). So in general it does make sense to guard against out-of-range input when dealing with curvilinear coordinates.

However, for angle variables as in this example, it's clearly a matter of taste what interval you define as the coordinate range, and it would absolutely be possible to treat this special case more intelligently, allowing any real number as angle input. After all, `FromPolarCoordinates` knows *ab initio* that the second entry *is* an angle.

In fact, this is done just fine in other built-in functions. For example, you can get the desired result (and therefore define this as a work-around) by using

```
RotationMatrix[(5 Pi)/3].{r, 0}

(* ==> {r/2, -((Sqrt[3] r)/2)} *)
```

The function `RotationMatrix` doesn't care about the valid input range, and the way I use it above it does exactly what you expect from the `FromPolarCoordinates` function. The role played by the angle variable in both functions is identical, so it would indeed be consistent if both functions treated angles the same way - which they don't.

Comment: Another possible factor in the decision is to ensure that FromPolarCoordinates and ToPolarCoordinates are exact inverses.

Comment: @SimonWoods Definitely a valid criterion. But in version 8, the old `CoordinatesToCartesian` did *not* have that property wrt. `CoordinatesFromCartesian` (i.e., all angle inputs were allowed), so it's also possible that this is just a consequence of some excessive internal streamlining where `FromPolarCoordinates` hands off the computation to a more general function that's unaware of the cyclic property of some coordinates... just guessing. In any case, I would then expect maybe just a warning message but it should still work for all angles.

Comment: @Simon, that's what I was referring to in my comment, since the output of `ArcTan[x, y]` is certainly within $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: @J.M. Except for `ArcTan[0,0]`...

Comment: Yes, `ToPolarCoordinates[]` also breaks in that case.

Comment: @J.M. I guess that's mathematically the right answer, but again `CoordinatesFromCartesian` does the "right thing" by giving $\phi=0$ without complaint. I think that was more useful.

Comment: "I think that was more useful." - ditto. Oh well.